# Python pandas. Group By and removing a timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below pandas data frame.  I need to do a Group By by column B and sum col A and remove the time stamp.  So..In the below...should have one record with the A's summed up.  Som How I do thus in pandas?

```
                               A  B
2013-03-15 17:00:00            1  134
2013-03-15 18:00:00          810  134
2013-03-15 19:00:00         1797  134
2013-03-15 20:00:00          813  134
2013-03-15 21:00:00         1323  134
2013-03-16 05:00:00           98  134
2013-03-16 06:00:00          515  134
2013-03-16 10:00:00          377  134
2013-03-16 11:00:00         1798  134
2013-03-16 12:00:00          985  134
2013-03-17 08:00:00          258  134
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a straight-forward groupby operation:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

content='''\
date time                               A  B
2013-03-15 17:00:00            1  134
2013-03-15 18:00:00          810  134
2013-03-15 19:00:00         1797  134
2013-03-15 20:00:00          813  135
2013-03-15 21:00:00         1323  134
2013-03-16 05:00:00           98  134
2013-03-16 06:00:00          515  135
2013-03-16 10:00:00          377  134
2013-03-16 11:00:00         1798  136
2013-03-16 12:00:00          985  136
2013-03-17 08:00:00          258  137'''

df = pd.read_table(io.BytesIO(content), sep='\s+',
                   parse_dates=[[0, 1]], header=0,
                   index_col=0)

print(df.groupby(['B']).sum())
```

yields

```
        A
B        
134  4406
135  1328
136  2783
137   258
```

Some of the values in `B` were changed to show a more interesting groupby operation.